# Terminal Page Down and Page Up For Laptop without PgDn and PgUp Keys

Tags: 16.04

I understand Terminal by default doesn't support PgDn and PgUp but is there an alternative to the linux terminal that supports this?

I have changed the location of my page down and page up on my keyboard and this appears to not work there. I do not have page down and page up keys on my keyboard.

Comment: What method have you used to map the PgUp/PgDn keys?

Comment: @wjandrea I would agree except there is no answer

Comment: Well, there is an answer there, and the answer is that it's not possible.

Comment: @wjandrea cygwin supports this it has to be possible

Comment: Cygwin is not Linux. While this feature is generally possible to have, it looks not be implemented in any terminal emulator in Linux (for whatever reasons).

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a terminal within Xwindows Place the mouse pointer over the window and you can use the scroll button to navigate. Otherwise your stuck with piping your output through `more` or `less` With `more` you can get a screen full at a time but there is no going back. With `less` you can cursor up and down which may be helpful to you. (Hence the phrase "less is more")

Comment: Yes @LiamWilliam it is basic stuff. So sorry, but the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

`gnome-terminal` supports scrolling using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> instead of <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd>.

Comment: I have changed the location of my page down and page up on my keyboard and this appears to not work there.  I do not have page down and page up keys on my keyboard.

Comment: I do not have PgDn and PgUp keys on my keyboard.